brew doctor: Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib. and Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include
When i run brew doctor i get

Warning: Some installed formulae are deprecated or disabled.
You should find replacements for the following formulae:
openssl@1.1
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
Unexpected dylibs:
/usr/local/lib/libwkextmac.dylib

Is there a way to solve this so that the error would disappear?
Would it be safe to delete those files?
I tried to upgrade the lib by promting:  brew upgrade libwkextmac but i only got :
Error: No available formula with the name "libwkextmac". Did you mean libwebm?
